# Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{a^2+bc}\leq{3\over2}(a+b+c)$ with $a,b,c$ are nonnegative

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials

Hope someone can help on this inequality using **nonanalytical** method (i.e. simple elementary method leveraging basic inequalities are prefered).

Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{a^2+bc}\leq{3\over2}(a+b+c)$ with $a,b,c$ are nonnegative.

Here is what I already got.

First of all, one should notice equality holds not when $a=b=c$ as one might initially thought. Rather, the equality holds when $(a,b,c)$ is a permutation of $({1\over2},{1\over2},0)$.

Secondly and obviously, this is cyclical and homgeneous and hence we can apply the EMV theorem developed by a IMO golden medalist (reference here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1130901) and then the original inequality can be easily proved by assuming $$f(a,b,c)={\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{a^2+bc}\over {a+b+c}},$$and then prove $$f(1,1,1)\leq{3\over2},\\f(a,b,0)\leq{3\over2},\forall a,b\geq0.$$

But this kind of proof does not fit my appetite as it not only involves some additional theorem but also not very **nice** as the simple nice form of the question of itself.

So can people help on some elementary proof that might only taking use of the basic inequalities like AM-GM, Jensen's inequality, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first we check $abc=0$,if $a=0 ,\implies 2\sqrt{bc}\le b+c$,it is true.the "=" will hold when $b=c$

in case $abc \not=0$

let $c=Max${$a,b,c$},

we discuss two cases:

1. $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge 2(ab+bc+ac) \implies c\ge a+b+2\sqrt{ab} \implies ab \le \dfrac{c^2}{16}$

LHS $\le\sqrt{a^2+bc}+\sqrt{b^2+ac}+\sqrt{c^2+\dfrac{c^2}{16}}\iff \sqrt{a^2+bc}+\sqrt{b^2+ac}+\dfrac{\sqrt{17}c}{4} \le \dfrac{3(a+b+c)}{2} \iff\sqrt{a^2+bc}+\sqrt{b^2+ac} \le \dfrac{3(a+b)+(3-\dfrac{\sqrt{17}}{2})c}{2} \iff 2 \sqrt{a^2+bc}\sqrt{b^2+ac}\le  p^2c^2+q(a+b)c+5a^2+5b^2+18ab \\ p=3-\dfrac{\sqrt{17}}{2}>0.8,q=14-3\sqrt{17}>1\\ \iff 4a^2b^2+4b^3c+4a^3c+4abc^2 \le \left( p^2c^2+q(a+b)c+5a^2+5b^2+18ab\right)^2 $

look at RHS, from$18ab$ we take $2ab$ to cover $4a^2b^2$, $16ab+p^2c^2 \implies 32p^2abc^2 >4abc^2,2*5a^2*qac >4a^3c,2*5b^2*qbc>4b^3c \implies LHS <RHS$

2 . $a^2+b^2+c^2 \le 2(ab+bc+ac)$ (that is why we exculde $abc=0$)

with $\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}{3} \le \sqrt{\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}}$

LHS $\le \sqrt{3(a^2+bc+b^2+ac+c^2+ab)} \iff \\ \sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ac)} \le \dfrac{3(a+b+c)}{2} \iff a^2+b^2+c^2 \le 2(ab+bc+ac) $

but first "=" will be hold when$a=b=c$, second "=" will hold when $c=a+b+2\sqrt{ab}$

so it is impossible to hold "=".

QED

Answer (score 1):

By C-S
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+bc}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2+bc}\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+b^2+c^2+bc).$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+bc}{2a^2+b^2+c^2+bc}\sum_{cyc}(4a^2+bc)\leq\frac{9(a+b+c)^2}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^8+2a^7b+2a^7c+9a^6b^2+9a^6c^2-23a^5b^3-23a^5c^3+20a^4b^4+11a^6bc+$$
$$+70a^5b^2c+70a^5c^2b+79a^4b^3c+79a^4c^3b+263a^4b^2c^2-195a^3b^3c^2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious because by Schur and Muirhead we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^8+2a^7b+2a^7c+9a^6b^2+9a^6c^2-23a^5b^3-23a^5c^3+20a^4b^4+11a^6bc+$$
$$+70a^5b^2c+70a^5c^2b+79a^4b^3c+79a^4c^3b+263a^4b^2c^2-195a^3b^3c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(4a^7b+4a^7c+9a^6b^2+9a^6c^2-23a^5b^3-23a^5c^3+20a^4b^4)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}ab(4a^6+9a^5b-23a^4b^2+20a^3b^3-23a^2b^4+9ab^5+4b^6)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}ab(a-b)^2(4a^4+17a^3b+7a^2b^2+17ab^3+4b^4)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Why this is obvious? 
Assume a=c=1, then expression = $ 20b^4 -159b^3+...$ may not be always greater than zero?

Comment: @Wangwang  I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Proof.

(i) if abc=0, W.L.O.G assume c=0, $\Longleftrightarrow a+b \geq 2\sqrt{ab}$, it is clearly true.

(ii) in the following, assume $abc > 0$.

Case 1: $a^2+b^2+c^2 \leq 2(ab+bc+ca)$

according to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have:
$$LHS \leq \sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)} \leq {3\over2}(a+b+c)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 3(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca) \leq {9\over4}(a+b+c)^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2 \leq 2(ab+bc+ca)$$

it is clearly true.

Case 2: $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq 2(ab+bc+ca)$

W.L.O.G. assume c=max{a,b,c},
according to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$\sqrt{a^2+bc} + \sqrt{b^2+ac} \leq \sqrt{2(a^2+b^2+ac+bc)}$$

and $$\sqrt{c^2+ab}=\sqrt{c^2+ab}-c+c=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{c^2+ab}+c} +c \leq \frac{ab}{2c} +c$$

$LHS \leq \sqrt{2(a^2+b^2+ac+bc)} + \frac{ab}{2c} +c \leq {3\over2}(a+b+c)$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{2(a^2+b^2+ac+bc)} \leq {3\over2}(a+b+c) - c - \frac{ab}{2c}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{2(a^2+b^2+ac+bc)} \leq {3\over2}(a+b) + {1\over2}c - \frac{ab}{2c}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 2(a^2+b^2+ac+bc) \leq ({3\over2}(a+b) + {1\over2}c - \frac{ab}{2c})^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{a^2b^2-6a^2bc-6ab^2c+a^2c^2+16abc^2+b^2c^2-2ac^3-2bc^3+c^4}{4c^2} \geq 0$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{a^2b^2+abc(16c-6a-6b)+c^2(a^2+b^2+c^2-2ac-2bc)}{4c^2} \geq 0$$

it is also true.